# WinJS is not defined error is there in web.api application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, winjs

I am new user for Microsoft asp.net web.api application.I am trying a dummy project where I have defined EmployeeController.cs , where there is a method for inserting employee in database.

```
 // POST api/<controller>
public void Post(EmployeeInfo empObj)
{
    objEmployeeDal.InsertEmployee(empObj);
}
```

In Employee.js file I am trying to access the web.api with post method to insert data.

```
  $('#btnAddEmployee').bind('click', function () {
    try {

        //Declare Object
        var Emp = {};
        Emp.firstName = $("#txtFirstName").val();
        Emp.MiddleName = $("#txtMiddleName").val();
        Emp.lastName = $("#txtLastName").val();
        Emp.gender = $('select#selectGender option:selected').val();
        Emp.roleID = "1";
        Emp.active = "1";
        //Get Url
        var createurl = "http://localhost:1045/api/Employee/";

        //POST data
        WinJS.xhr({
            type: "POST",
            url: createurl,
            headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
            data: JSON.stringify(Emp)
        }).then(success, error);

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }

});
```

and also include the WinJS file in employee HTML page.

```
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/EmployeeDetails.js"></script>
```

But in firebug it showing issue " WinJS is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

The script tag you're using to bring in winjs will only work in a win8 application, not in a web page. Based on you mentioning firebug, I'm assuming you're trying to use it in a normal web app. You'll need to put the winjs files on your web server and access them like you would any other script file.

But be aware: winjs has not been designed or tested for cross browser scenarios, and check the license for the library. At least some versions only allowed use in win8 apps. I'm not sure if that's still the case in the final release, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is.

Comment: Thanks. I am also in same doubt that may be I have to use this in windows 8 metro application.I am using it normal web application and Microsoft also not support fully for this library.